# code not working with shareactionprovider but same code work with menu option

Tags: android, shareactionprovider

I am using shareactionprovider to share the text but cannot get it to work.The same code works fine with the menu option. When I share text using shareactionprovider text is not shared but when I share same text using menu share option text gets shared.

sorry for my poor english

```
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
        getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.share2, menu);
        menu.add(Menu.NONE, MENU_ITEM1, Menu.NONE, "Share");
        MenuItem mShareActionProviderItem = (MenuItem) menu.findItem(R.id.menu_share2);

        mShareActionProvider = (ShareActionProvider) mShareActionProviderItem.getActionProvider();

        Intent t = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        t.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        t.setType("text/plain");
        CharSequence displayContents = contentsTextView.getText().toString();
        t.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,displayContents);
        mShareActionProvider.setShareIntent(t);
        return true;  
    }


    @Override
     public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
         switch (item.getItemId()) {



        case MENU_ITEM1:

                Intent shareIntent2 = new Intent();
                shareIntent2.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                shareIntent2.setType("text/plain");
                CharSequence displayContents2 = contentsTextView.getText().toString();
                shareIntent2.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,displayContents2);
                startActivity(shareIntent2);
                break;




            }
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
     }
```

Answer (score 1):

`contentsTextView` is probably empty when `onCreateOptionsMenu()` is called.

Instead, update the `Intent` as the user types:

```
/***
  Copyright (c) 2012 CommonsWare, LLC
  Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License"); you may not
  use this file except in compliance with the License. You may obtain        a copy
  of the License at http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0. Unless required
  by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software distributed under the
  License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,        WITHOUT        WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS
  OF ANY KIND, either express or implied. See the License for the specific
  language governing permissions and limitations under the License.

  From _The Busy Coder's Guide to Android Development_
    http://commonsware.com/Android
*/

package com.commonsware.android.sap;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;
import com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockActivity;
import com.actionbarsherlock.view.Menu;
import com.actionbarsherlock.widget.ShareActionProvider;

public class MainActivity extends SherlockActivity implements
    ShareActionProvider.OnShareTargetSelectedListener, TextWatcher {
  private ShareActionProvider share=null;
  private Intent shareIntent=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
  private EditText editor=null;

  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
    super.onCreate(icicle);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    shareIntent.setType("text/plain");
    editor=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editor);
    editor.addTextChangedListener(this);
  }

  @Override
  public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getSupportMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.actions, menu);

    share=
        (ShareActionProvider)menu.findItem(R.id.share)
                                 .getActionProvider();
    share.setOnShareTargetSelectedListener(this);

    return(super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu));
  }

  @Override
  public boolean onShareTargetSelected(ShareActionProvider source,
                                       Intent intent) {
    Toast.makeText(this, intent.getComponent().toString(),
                   Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    return(false);
  }

  @Override
  public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
    shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, s.toString());
    share.setShareIntent(shareIntent);
  }

  @Override
  public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                                int after) {
    // ignored
  }

  @Override
  public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
                            int count) {
    // ignored
  }
}
```

(as seen in [this sample project](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/ActionBar/Share))

Comment: FYI there's a (bizarre) related problem, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22665226 with three full duplicate questions and not one answer!